# Prevent iPad from charging while connected to MacBook Pro

Tags: ipad, charging

I would like to know how to prevent an iPad/iPhone/iPod Touch from charging while connected to the USB port on a MacBook on battery power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. USB includes 5v power, and I think it happens on a hardware level. As in, it can't be turned off without modifying the connectors or the hardware in some way. Not worth while.

Comment: However, if you connect a unpowered USB extension wire or hub to the port, the iDevice should not be able to charge.